# What is difference between MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation and MessageBoxIcon.Warning?

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is difference between MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation and MessageBoxIcon.Warning?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847313/why-does-system-windows-messageboximage-have-enumeration-sub-items-with-the-same

Answer (score 19):

There is no difference, they are aliases for the same number (48).

```
public enum MessageBoxIcon
{
   None = 0,
   Error = 16,
   Hand = 16,
   Stop = 16,
   Question = 32,
   Exclamation = 48,
   Warning = 48,
   Asterisk = 64,
   Information = 64,
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

They are synonyms. Same thing. Shows identical icons.

In fact, they are both equal to 48.

Answer (score 0):

A simple google would have sufficed...

[MessageBoxIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx)

**Exclamation**: `The message box contains a symbol consisting of an exclamation point in a triangle with a yellow background.`

**Warning**: `The message box contains a symbol consisting of an exclamation point in a triangle with a yellow background.`

So not much...

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx

Exclamation     The message box contains a symbol consisting of an exclamation point in a triangle with a yellow background.

Warning     The message box contains a symbol consisting of an exclamation point in a triangle with a yellow background.

Soo...... nothing!