# Several sound types

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to get several sounds types. Found that I can get only two types of system sound.

Plays the same sound type:

```
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
```

Plays another sound type:

```
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
```

Why first three functions plays the same sound and how to get more sounds without adding audio files?

Comment: I guess this depends on your Windows sounds scheme (exact sound) and can be different on another machine

Comment: You can assign them different sounds with Control Panel > Sounds, but the only thing you are likely to find out is that programmers just had no idea which one was appropriate.  Hard-coding c:\windows\media is one way to get it more predictable, but not exactly a great substitute for supplying your own.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203468/what-is-difference-between-messageboxicon-exclamation-and-messageboxicon-warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`System.Media.SystemSounds`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/Media/SystemSounds.cs,71c9c37060445ca1) relies on [`MessageBeep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebeep).

It plays a sound based on sound scheme which is set in control panel (and stored in registery). The scheme can be disabled or set by user at  Control Panel → Sounds → Sounds Tab:

[image]