# Why is this MessageBoxImage enum value messed up?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, enums

I have a complex WPF application, in that application I'm converting between a MessageBoxIcon enumeration used by a third party UI library, and the `System.Windows.MessageBoxImage` enumeration. However what should be a really simple conversion method (just a switch statement) is actually returning nonsense. I haven't been able to work out why this is, but I have reduced it to a very simple demo.

Here is a really simple WPF application.

```cs
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows;

    public static class Test
    {
        public static MessageBoxImage GetImage()
        {
            MessageBoxImage image = MessageBoxImage.Error;
            Trace.WriteLine("Test.GetImage, image: " + image);
            return image;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MessageBoxImage image = Test.GetImage();
            Trace.WriteLine("OnStartup, image: " + image);
        }
    }
}
```

The two trace messages output:

```
Test.GetEnum, image: Hand
OnStartup, image: Hand
```

But why? Why do they not output Error instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MessageBoxImage enum has 3 values, Error, Hand and Stop, all with the same numeric value, 16. That is why you can get an other value than the one you set.

Look here e.g: [Why does System.Windows.MessageBoxImage have enumeration sub-items with the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847313/why-does-system-windows-messageboximage-have-enumeration-sub-items-with-the-same).